# .bak file is not opening

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Im following the following but still not succeeded

1. Created empty database TestingDb in sql server 2008
2. Database(right-click) --> Restore databases
3. In To DataBase field wrote TestingDb.
4. Select From devices and browse address of .bak file then ok

Still it's giving an error: System.data.sqlclient: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'TestDb' Database

Comment: select option Overwrite existing db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create an empty database in order to restore your backup file.

Use Databases(right-click)\Restore database...

Comment: Databases(right-click)\Restore database ., after this it's asking for To data base., What should i select for To data base. ? in To Db list it's showing list of previously made Dbs.